# Passing environment variables via sudo on solaris 10

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, solaris

I need to execute a command via sudo on Solaris 10, and I need to pass two environment variables to the command. This must be done in `/bin/sh`, not `bash`, not `ksh`.

This is possible on Linux, serveral options exist there, but they do not work on solaris, as solaris' `sudo` does not support the `-E` switch we have on Linux. Installing a more modern version of sudo also not really an option.

The only workaround I can think of is to put the command together with the variables into a script, like

```
#!/bin/sh
a=foo
b=bar
export a
export b
my_command
```

then execute that script via sudo. However this kind of circumvents security, as now I need to allow that script via sudo, which is bad practise, as the script could be edited, so I can not control what I am actually granting.

Any ideas?

EDIT: The variables I wanted to pass are LD_PRELOAD LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Since the command via sudo was executed in a single purpose chroot, I was able to copy the libraries referenced by the variables to standard locations, overwriting some "system" libraries. Please Note that this is not good practice in general (I would strongly recommend against it), however in this case - single purpose chroot - I found it to be a pragmatic solution.

Comment: What version of sudo are you using? As far as I can tell, Solaris 10 doesn't come with it, and the sunfreeware version is 1.8.10p2.

Comment: From a Solaris 10 user on superuser.com: [How do I make sudo preserve my environment variables](https://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables)

Comment: Thank you @MarkPlotnick for your suggestions. I tried to avoid editing the sudo conf, and yes, looks like my sudo is 1.8 something. I was able to work around the problem with a hack (see my edit).